# Cloud broker application for hybrid clouds

Tags: cloud, virtualization

Currently, I support Amazon EC2/AWS instances along with Microsoft Azure, VMWare vCloud Director and ESX VM instances. I use puppet and chef to provision various types of servers (Linux/JBoss, MS 2008, 2012, BizTalk). I am looking for an open source cloud broker application where the developers would be able to chose which platform, sizing, OS and application stack, similar to the functionality of Cloud66.

I've looked into the Deltacloud project (http://deltacloud.apache.org) but was wondering are there any others that are also in this space - CompatibleOne or openQRM (http://www.openqrm-enterprise.com/community/) ?!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a library to deploy across different platform/providers - but manage your engagements with different providers by yourself - deltacloud or [jClouds](http://jclouds.org) would work for you.

From your description and reference to Cloud66, it looks like you are looking for a service that enables you to provision VMs and deploy applications to different cloud providers. You can use the [ComputeNext](http://www.computenext.com) Cloud Service Marketplace to search and chose based on provider, platform, size, OS, etc., procure and provision VMs/Servers. With a single account, you have a common API to provision cloud services from multiple cloud providers.

CompatibleOne offers the ability for you to define your server requirements and broker the provisioning and deployment in different platforms - AWS, OpenStack, Azure, etc. A connector or PROCCI for ComputeNext is included in CompatibleOne. This will enable you to get brokering in hybrid cloud setting - For example, you can use OSPROCCI to provision/deploy to your private OpenStack cloud and CNPROCCI to provision and deploy to the cloud provider in ComputeNext Marketplace.

Disclaimer: I am the CTO of ComputeNext.